# Отсутствует доступ к сервлету

Tags: java, servlet

Изучаю тему сервлетов. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что html и jsp работают, однако когда я пытаюсь зайти на страницу сервлета (адрес http://localhost:8080/SE/hello), то возникает следующая ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено
Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Ниже прикладываю свои файлы.
**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SE</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**SE.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SE extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Readers</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Искал в интернете решение проблемы, но у меня многое отличается:

1. Не пользуюсь IDE. Пишу код в блокноте и компилю через консоль. Так требуют.
2. Я понимаю, что ссылка видна, то есть путь прописан правильно (/hello), но нет доступа к сервлету. Уже более недели пытаюсь решить, но всё тщетно. Забыл сказать, я использую tomcat. Самая главная страница(localhost:8080) загружается без проблем. То есть всё работает, но в своём проекте не могу разобраться...

Comment: когда  вы пытаетесь зайти на страницу сервлета (адрес http://localhost:8080/SE/hello), вы отправляете `GET` запрос, а в коде ваш сервлет `SE ` обрабатывает только `POST` запросы (`public void doPost(...)`)

Comment: @azlov Спасибо тебе. Этот момент я изменил. Однако всё равно страница не грузится